# Webcenter Sites: Configure Gmail SMTP Server

Tags: email, smtp, gmail

I can´t configure my SMTP Server to send workflow notifications.

I´ve tried both protocols SSL and TLS.

**These are my properties:**

```
futuretense.ini:cs.emailauthenticator=com.openmarket.framework.mail.ICSAuthenticator futuretense.ini:cs.emailcontenttype= futuretense.ini:cs.emailhost=smtp.gmail.com:465 or tls://smtp.gmail.com:587 futuretense.ini:cs.emailaccount=dummy@gmail.com futuretense.ini:cs.emailpassword=dummy123 futuretense.ini:cs.emailcharset= futuretense.ini:cs.emailreturnto=
```

**The error is:**

> (with SSL) [fatwire.logging.cs.xml] Error: mail.send failed! Message
>   exception sending mail Sending failed; nested exception is:
>   javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host:
>   smtp.gmail.com, port: 465
>
> (with TLS) [fatwire.logging.cs.xml] Error: mail.send failed! Message
>   exception sending mail Sending failed; nested exception is:
>   javax.mail.MessagingException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command
>   first. ww4sm18327270wjc.47 - gsmtp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to send over SSL/TLS, only SMTP. As a workaround you can set up a local SMTP mail server that forwards everything over SSL/TLS to your eventual mail server, and then configure Sites to send to your local SMTP server.